# Layer: Set corder radius then add a shadow

Tags: swift, uikit

I want an image to appear as a circle with a shadow. Doing the following don't work because the shadow is probably cut off by the clipping...

```
let layer = myImageView.layer
// cut circle
layer.borderWidth = 1
layer.masksToBounds = false
layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
layer.cornerRadius = myImageView.frame.height/2
myImageView.clipsToBounds = true
// add shadow
layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 10)
layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
layer.shadowRadius = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem...

I solve this by putting an image on top of the button(in my case was a button not an image) to act like a shadow.

```
button.sizeToFit()
shadow.layer.cornerRadius = 6
shadow.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
shadow.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
shadow.layer.shadowRadius = 6
shadow.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2) 
button.layer.cornerRadius = 6
button.clipsToBounds = true
```

*shadow* is the imageView that will be the shadow, of course.

*button* in your case will be your image.